# LoginForm hides or closes automatically when the ShowInTaskBar property is false

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am developing an application in C# Winforms with system login where I have two forms, one being the main `MainForm` and the other which is for the login `LoginForm`.

This application has a `Modern Flat UI Design` interface, so it wants the `LoginForm form` is displayed in front of the `MainForm` form, to not display its icon in the taskbar and not allow the user to interact with `MainForm` to display it's been use of the method `ShowDialog();`.

`LoginForm` compacted code:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.ShowInTaskbar = this.ShowIcon = false;
    }
}
```

`MainForm` compacted code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        new LoginForm().ShowDialog();
        //new LoginForm().ShowDialog(this);
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);

        //new LoginForm().ShowDialog();
        //new LoginForm().ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

My problem is that nothing else to start `MainForm`, shows the `LoginForm` for about 2 seconds and then hides it, then, I minimize the `MainForm` to verify that the `LoginForm` has not moved behind `MainForm`, but it turns out that `LoginForm` is not there.

If I remove the property `ShowInTaskbar = false;` then everything works normally, but the `LoginForm` is displayed in the taskbar which is precisely what I do not want.

So, **how can I show my `LoginForm` in front of `MainForm` without `LoginForm` appearing in the taskbar?**

**Note**:
Yes, while the `LoginForm` is not closed, the user not may interact with `MainForm` and the only way to close the `LoginForm` is logging properly or by clicking on the button close the `LoginForm` calling `Application.Exit();`.

Also, I've tried to hide the `MainForm` to start with `this.Hide();` but equally `LoginForm` disappears.

Comment: new LoginForm().ShowDialog(Me); ? then it wont go behind the mainform

Comment: @Ctznkane525 is C# not VB and yes, I already tried with `new LoginForm().ShowDialog(this);`, but, the result is the same

Comment: Can''t reproduce. When I override `OnShown`, the `LoginForm` shows on top of `MainForm` without issue, has no task bar button or icon, and does not disappear. Could be an issue with the way you are launching MainForm; please post that portion of your code.

Comment: It seems you should set `ShowInTaskbar` of the modal form before creating its handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ShowInTaskBar` and `ShowIcon` in constructor of your dialog:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.ShowIcon = false;
    }
}
```

And then show it in `Shown` method of the main form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        new LoginForm().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you should set `ShowInTaskbar` of the modal form before creating its handle.

Comment: You can refactor the code based on your requirement. I simply call it like `new Form(){ShowInTaskbar = false, ShowIcon=false}.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the parent of the login form to the main form.